# Flutter Pdf Network Image Printing with data from FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, pdf, printing

i have some troubles with the Flutter pdf & printing package.
I am getting the NetworkImage data from a FutureBuilder with POST method as url (https://192.168.xxx.xxx/xxx.jpg) and i want to show the Networkimage at the PDFPreview
but it is only showing the first image and the others as duplicate.
this is my code:

```
Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format, AsyncSnapshot snapshot,
    BuildContext context, int index) async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();

  final image =
      await flutterImageProvider(NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].img));

  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (context) {
        return pw.ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return pw.Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: pw.Row(
                children: [
                  pw.Image(image),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );

  return pdf.save();
}
```

[Gridview.Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PidtL.png)

[PdfPreview with duplicated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDB4Z.png)

Comment: I think you need to move `final image = await flutterImageProvider(NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].img));` inside of the `itemBuilder`, before returning the `pw.Container()`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it needs to be in  async

Comment: You need to work out resolving the Future into a Widget you can use but I think your original problem is solved by assigning the image within the `itemBuilder` of the `ListView.builder`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format, AsyncSnapshot snapshot,
    BuildContext context, int index) async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();

  // image is only being assigned to once
  final image =
      await flutterImageProvider(NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].img));

  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (context) {
        return pw.ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) { // <- image never changes during build
            return pw.Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: pw.Row(
                children: [
                  pw.Image(image),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );

  return pdf.save();
}
```

Try changing it to

```
Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format, AsyncSnapshot snapshot,
    BuildContext context, int index) async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  
  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (context) {
        return pw.ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return FutureBuilder(
              future: flutterImageProvider(NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].img)),
              builder: (context, imageSnapshot) {
                if (imageSnapshot.hasData) {
                  return pw.Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 50,
                    child: pw.Row(
                      children: [
                        pw.Image(imageSnapshot.data),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text('waiting for image...');
                }
              });
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );

  return pdf.save();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply than i get an error: The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.

Comment: See the updated answer. It should be wrapped in a future builder. Obviously, you can replace the `Text('waiting for image...')` with any widget you want, it will be displayed while waiting on the Future to resolve.

Comment: The return type 'FutureBuilder<ImageProvider>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context. cant build Futurebuilder inside of PdfWidget :(

Comment: What is `pw`? Where do you get it?

Comment: ```import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;```